# Does Solidity language has namespace?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, nft

In Solidity langugae, I define `ContractA` and `ContractB`.

Inside `ContractA` declare structure `A` and I want to access `A` inside `ContractB`.

```
contract ContractA {
  struct A {
  uint age;
  string name;
  }

  // Some other methods and data structure
}

contract ContractB {
  // how to access structure A.
}
```

I don't want to use Inheritance or `library` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like namespace of C# in Solidity.

If you would like to share the struct between contract, then declare a library.

```
library Structs {
    struct AnyName {
        uint256 id;
    }
}

contract ContractA {
    Structs.AnyName go;
}
```